# Angle between 2 arc of circle on a sphere

Tags: python, spherical-geometry

I have 4 points with (lat, long) coordinates. Lets say

A = (lat_A, lon_A)

B = (lat_B, lon_B)

C = (lat_C, lon_C)

D = (lat_D, lon_D)

A and B make the first arc, C and D the second. I would like to compute the angle between these 2 arcs.

I can see that these arcs make a great circle on my sphere and calculate the angle between these arcs would be equivalent to calculate the angle between the 2 circles.

I also tried using median point and azimuth but the result doesnt seem to be correct.

Here is my code :

```
import math as m

def midpoint(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # median point between 2 points on a sphere
    mid_lat = m.radians((lat1 + lat2) / 2)
    mid_lon = m.radians((lon1 + lon2) / 2)
    return mid_lat, mid_lon

def azimuth(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # compute azimut between 2 points on the sphere
    delta_lon = lon2 - lon1
    azimuth = m.atan2(m.sin(delta_lon) * m.cos(lat2), 
                      m.cos(lat1)*m.sin(lat2)-m.sin(lat1)*m.cos(lat2)*m.cos(delta_lon))
    return azimuth

def angle_between_arcs(A, B, C, D):
    # median point
    center_AB = midpoint(A[0], A[1], B[0], B[1])
    center_CD = midpoint(C[0], C[1], D[0], D[1])

    # azimuth
    azimuth_A = azimuth(center_AB[0], center_AB[1], A[0], A[1])
    azimuth_B = azimuth(center_AB[0], center_AB[1], B[0], B[1])

    azimuth_C = azimuth(center_CD[0], center_CD[1], C[0], C[1])
    azimuth_D = azimuth(center_CD[0], center_CD[1], D[0], D[1])

    # difference
    angle_diff = m.degrees(abs(azimuth_pg1 - azimuth_po1) - abs(azimuth_pg2 - azimuth_po2))

    return angle_diff
```

EDIT

I finally found my answer and i'm pretty sure it will be usefull to somebody one day.

First you have to understand that and arc of circle given by two points on the globe define a great circle with the center of the earth as center.

Then you have two great circles and you want to get the angle between these circle.
These two circles intersect each other in two points on the globe, and you want to get the angle of the closest point.

Here is the python code :

```
def sphericalToCartesian(longitude, latitude):

# deg to radians
lat_rad = math.radians(latitude)
lon_rad = math.radians(longitude)

# to cartesian
x = math.cos(lat_rad) * math.cos(lon_rad)
y = math.cos(lat_rad) * math.sin(lon_rad)
z = math.sin(lat_rad)
return x, y, z

def cartesianToSpherical(x, y, z):
    lat = math.asin(z) * 180./np.pi
    lon = math.atan2(y, x) * 180./np.pi
    return lon, lat

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance in kilometers between two 
points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # to radians
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, 
lat2])

    # haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * 
math.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 
    return c * r

def getIntersectionPoints(point1_cercle1, point2_cercle1, 
point1_cercle2, point2_cercle2):
 
    # each pair allows to create a great circle around the globe
    # to cartesian first
    p1c1x, p1c1y, p1c1z = sphericalToCartesian(*point1_cercle1)
    p2c1x, p2c1y, p2c1z = sphericalToCartesian(*point2_cercle1)

    p1c2x, p1c2y, p1c2z = sphericalToCartesian(*point1_cercle2)
    p2c2x, p2c2y, p2c2z = sphericalToCartesian(*point2_cercle2)


    # normal of each plan corresponding to a great circle
    norm1 = np.cross([p1c1x, p1c1y, p1c1z], [p2c1x, p2c1y, p2c1z])
    norm2 = np.cross([p1c2x, p1c2y, p1c2z], [p2c2x, p2c2y, p2c2z])

    # intersection of normals
    line = np.cross(norm1, norm2)

    # two points opposed on earth
    p0 = line / np.sqrt(line[0]**2 + line[1]**2 + line[2]**2)
    p1 = -p0

    # to (lon, lat)
    i_long0, i_lat0 = cartesianToSpherical(*p0)
    i_long1, i_lat1 = cartesianToSpherical(*p1)

    # lets keep the closest point
    dist_i0, dist_i1 = haversine(i_long0, i_lat0, *point1_cercle1), 
haversine(i_long1, i_lat1, *point1_cercle1)
    if dist_i0 < dist_i1:
        i_point = (i_long0, i_lat0)
    else:
        i_point = (i_long1, i_lat1)
    return i_point


def getAngleInSphericalTriangle(point_0, point_1, point_2):
    """
        point_0 is a point of your first great circle or arc of 
circle
        point_1 is the intersection point
        point_2 is a point of your 2nd great circle or arc of 
circle
    """
    # to cartesian
    cart_p0 = sphericalToCartesian(*point_0)
    cart_p1 = sphericalToCartesian(*point_1)
    cart_p2 = sphericalToCartesian(*point_2)

    # angle between points and earth center
    p1p2 = np.arccos(np.dot(cart_p1, cart_p2))
    p0p1 = np.arccos(np.dot(cart_p0, cart_p1))
    p2p0 = np.arccos(np.dot(cart_p2, cart_p0))

    #  third fundamental law of spherical trigonometry
    angle_radian = np.arccos((np.cos(p2p0) - 
np.cos(p0p1)*np.cos(p1p2))/(np.sin(p0p1)*np.sin(p1p2)))
    angle_degre = np.degrees(angle_radian)
    return angle_degre
```

Comment: I cannot really show you how this angle looks like. But the sphere correspond to the globe, and the arcs does not necessarily pass through the pole. I can make you a drawing if you want but i might not be the best haha.

Comment: This looks like a pure maths question rather than GIS.

Comment: If you've found an answer to your question, post it as an answer rather than editing your question ;)